# finding "active" branch in EGIT repository

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, jgit

I have to modify a faulty program/feature, which is an extension to org.eclipse.jgit

the program overrides the close method of the PushResultDialog and passes the Repository to an method.
Here i want to find the branch which was actually pushed/checked out. I am only interested if its the master, if not i don't wanna do anything.
else i need the list of the pushed files.

First the program looked like this :

```
    head = repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
        RevCommit commit = rw.parseCommit(head);

        PersonIdent committerIdent = commit.getCommitterIdent();
        sCommitter = committerIdent.getName();

        String sBranch = "?";

        for (Map.Entry<String, Ref> e : repo.getAllRefs().entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().startsWith(Constants.R_HEADS)) {
                Ref ref = e.getValue();
                if (rw.isMergedInto(commit, rw.parseCommit(ref.getObjectId()))) {
                    sTemp = ref.getName();

                    int i = sTemp.lastIndexOf('/');
                    if (i == -1)
                        continue;

                    sBranch = sTemp.substring(i + 1);

                    System.out.println("Ref " + sBranch 
                            + " < contains > " + commit);

                    if (sBranch.equalsIgnoreCase("master")) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        RevCommit parent = rw.parseCommit(commit.getParent(0).getId());
        DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(
                DisabledOutputStream.INSTANCE);
        df.setRepository(repo);
        df.setDiffComparator(RawTextComparator.DEFAULT);
        df.setDetectRenames(true);
        List<DiffEntry> diffs = df.scan(parent.getTree(),
                commit.getTree());
        for (DiffEntry diff : diffs) {
            sTemp = diff.getNewPath();
            pushedObjects.add(sTemp);
        }
```

now .. this works as long as the workflow in eclipse is just "checkout master" "pull" "merge branch" "push"

any other order seems to mess with the order of the branches in the set, and it stumbles over this "else" :

```
if (sBranch.equalsIgnoreCase("master")) {
      break;
 } else {
      return;
 }
```

the question is : is there an eaasy method to pick the right branch?

Comment: First, you cannot assume a unordered set will maintain any order (that's why it's unordered). And second, you cannot assume there's a branch called "master" (although it is usually the case).

Comment: i have to assume there's a branch called master, it is standard in our company and HAS to be there. but you are right, there is no order, thats my problem. ATM i am wondering if i can get the last commit with `RevCommit commit = rw.parseCommit(repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD));` and then just replace `rw.isMergedInto(commit, rw.parseCommit(ref.getObjectId()))` with `commit.equals(rw.parseCommit(ref.getObjectId()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think i can simply look at the HEAD in the set:

```
e.getKey().startsWith(Constants.HEAD)
```

and then parse the branchname, that should always be the branch which is checked out, if (in my case),if it is the master, i am happy.